# How to filter ads in Facebook Marketting insight by type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I want to filter ads in Insight by type of ads.

Currently, I am using this. It returns all ads whether it is photo, link, or video.

```
graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XXXXXXXXXXXX/insights?fields=ad_id,ad_nameadset_name,impressions,reach,relevance_score,date_start,date_stop&level=ad
```

I want to filter ads by type in this. I want to get ads with link type in return.

Or is there any parameter so that it returns the type of ads. So that I know the type of ads from the result returned from graph.

Comment: Check the parameters and fields listed in the docs. If there is no parameter to filter by type and the type is not in the field list - then the answer is no.

Comment: @CBroe "If there is no *some thing* in docs, then it's not possible" is not always true for Marketing API. There are a lot of hidden things, that you can find via hacking Business Manager or by luck.

Comment: I found a field named "action" which return link_clicks if the ads contain links.

So from this I can check if the ad has link.
Hope this may help others. Still someone has exact solution so please help. Or I'll go with that..

Answer (score 0):

The Insights API does not currently support creating a breakdown, or grouping of insights based on ad type. We keep a list of possible breakdowns current here, which are autogenerated based on available breakdowns in the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns.